# How to split a String while ignoring special strings

Tags: c#, string, split

Say i have a string that required Split by {" ",". "}.
the given string containing full name that cannot be splitted.

**for example**

```
fullString = "Jhon Due was drawing the quick brown fox. Alex King draw a fox"
splitSeperatorArray =  {",", " "}
ignoreSplitArray = {"Jhon Due", "Alex King"}
```

The desired result is:

> {"Jhon Due", "was", "drawing", "the", "quick", brown", vfox", "Alex
>   King", "draw", "a", "fox"}

Will appreciate information about the right approche when it comes to large data processing.

***Thanks!***

Comment: Do you need the items in `ignoreSplitArray` to be in your result at the correct position, or does the position of items in result not matter?

Comment: i have to maintain the items in currect order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with regular expressions. Try this code:

```
var fullString = "Jhon Due was drawing,the quick brown fox. Alex King draw a fox";
var ignoreSplitArray = new[] {"Jhon Due", "Alex King"};

var ignore = string.Join("|", ignoreSplitArray);
var regex = new Regex($" |,|({ignore})");
var result = regex.Split(fullString).Where(s => s.Length > 0).ToArray();
```

Comment: thats what i was looking for. thanks. very sharp approche!

Answer (score 1):

You can not do this with split only. For example you can split and then search the result if there are any special strings and then make your final result.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using *regular expressions* instead of `Split`; we can try including  names like `John Due` and `Alex King` *into a pattern* instead of maintaining an array of them (which is difficult when performing *large* data processing):

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string source = "John Due was drawing the quick brown fox. Alex King draws a fox";
string pattern = @"([A-Z][a-z]+(\s[A-Z][a-z]+)*)|([a-z]+)";

var result = Regex
  .Matches(source, pattern)
  .OfType<Match>()
  .Select(match => match.Value);

Console.Write(string.Join("; ", result));
```

Outcome:

```
John Due; was; drawing; the; quick; brown; fox; Alex King; draws; a; fox
```

**Edit:** If *numbers* (see comments) can appear in the text, you have to include them into the `pattern`, e.g

```
string source = "John111 Due was drawing the quick 123 brown fox. Alex King draws a fox";
string pattern = @"([A-Z][a-z0-9]+(\s[A-Z][a-z0-9]+)*)|([a-z0-9]+)";
...
```

Outcome:

```
John111 Due; was; drawing; the; quick; 123; brown; fox; Alex King; draws; a; fox
```

Another possibility

```
string source = 
 "John111 Due (Джон Дью) was drawing the quick 123 [۰۱۲] brown fox. Alex King draws a fox";

string pattern = @"(\p{Lu}\w+(\s\p{Lu}\w+)*)|(\w+)";
```

if you want to extract non-English letters (e.g. Russian) and digits (e.g. Persian)

Outcome:

```
John111 Due; Джон Дью; was; drawing; the; quick; 123; ۰۱۲; brown; fox; Alex King; draws; a; fox
```

Comment: I've changed `source ` to "Jhon1111 Due ..."  and `ignoreSplitArray` to "{ "Jhon1111 Due", ...". Please try it yourself

Comment: this is nice approche but too generic for my case. say i have string without uppercase, it won't work. thank  you for the description.